# What does MANUFACTURER: CE80 mean?

Tags: dmidecode

What's the meaning of `Manufacturer: CE80` in a memory description when listing with command `sudo dmidecode -t memory`? (Ubuntu 15.10)

Comment: Can you give the full output from the command edited into your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to find a full list of manufacturer codes but this particular code is associated with Samsung:

```
0x80CE—Samsung Electronics, Inc.
```

This is taken from a table on the page I have listed as reference, the full section of this table going:

```
The vendor ID of the manufacturer. This can be one of the following:

    0x2C00—Micron Technology, Inc.
    0x5105—Qimonda AG i. In.
    0x802C—Micron Technology, Inc.
    0x80AD—Hynix Semiconductor Inc.
    0x80CE—Samsung Electronics, Inc.
    0x8551—Qimonda AG i. In.
    0xAD00—Hynix Semiconductor Inc.
    0xCE00—Samsung Electronics, Inc.
```

**References:**

- [Cisco: Viewing server properties - Memory Properties](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/c/sw/gui/config/guide/151/b_Cisco_UCS_C-series_GUI_Configuration_Guide-151/b_Cisco_UCS_C-series_GUI_Configuration_Guide-151_chapter_0100.html#task_10637AC91E1C4F55ABEC112C91AD29EA)