# what does manufacturer: 443 mean?

Tags: ram

When I run dmidecode on my thinkpad T420, I get

Manufaturer: 0443

Which company is this?

This question is similar to https://askubuntu.com/a/755352/930656 .But I don't find a answer there.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Lenovo ThinkPad T420s [reference](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=53037be14e&log=dmidecode) at https://linux-hardware.org/ `Manufacturer 0443` code refers to Ramaxel, e.g. Ramaxel RMT3170EF68F9W1600 4GB DDR RAM memory, 1600MHz.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you have a document anywhere for reference? Would this  be compatible with Kingston memory?

Comment: Lenovo ThinkPad T420s [link for reference](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=53037be14e&log=dmidecode)  (https://linux-hardware.org). This hardware would be compatible with any generic 4GB DDR 1600MHz RAM stick where 4GB is the RAM size, DDR is the RAM type, and 1600MHz is the clock speed.